# CSS transform skew without blur

Tags: css, fonts, css-transforms

I'm trying to create some drivers with a border and text. The drivers need to be tilted so I have applied the `transform: skew();` CSS rule. However, now the font and the border have gone really blurry. I understand it is possible to add font smoothing to an element but I'm not sure how to smooth my border as well?

I would like these drivers to be full width of the browser, with no white space after the skew.

CSS -

```
.flex-inline{
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display: -ms-flexbox;
   display: flex;
}
.driver-wrap{
   overflow: hidden;
   margin-bottom: 75px;
}   
.driver{
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
  min-height: 250px;
  position: relative;
  transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}      
.content{
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/oKWAofK.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -50px;
  right: -50px;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: skew(15deg, 0deg);
}         
.text{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 75px;
  width: 70%;
  transform: rotate(360deg);
}
h2{
  font-family: $heading;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
p{
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.driver:nth-child(1){
  margin-left: -50px;
  border-right: 20px solid #fdcb6e;

}
.driver:nth-child(2){
  border-right: 20px solid #e84393;
}
```

HTML -

```
<div class="driver-wrap flex-inline">
    <div class="driver">
        <div class="content">
       <div class="text">
               <h2>Building training</h2>
          <p>lorem ipsum text here</p>
       </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="driver">
        <div class="content">
       <div class="text">
               <h2>Building training</h2>
          <p>lorem ipsum text here</p>
       </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="driver">
        <div class="content">
       <div class="text">
               <h2>Building training</h2>
          <p>lorem ipsum text here</p>
       </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle - 
https://jsfiddle.net/zhhpm02y/10/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have yet to see any pure CSS solution to fix blurry text after a transform - but I'm happy to be proven wrong!

I've found it best to never skew or transform text and instead skew the image, border etc., then just position the text over the top. For example:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: -54px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

article {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

section {
  min-width: 300px;
  margin-top: 130px;
  margin-left: 70px;
}

aside {
  background-image: url('https://i.redd.it/kvowi2zio7h01.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg);
  transform-origin: bottom center;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

aside::after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  border-right: 20px solid #fdcb6e;
}

article:nth-child(2n) aside::after {
  border-right-color: #e84393;
}

h2 {
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}

p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <article>
    <section>
      <h2>Building training</h2>
      <p>lorem ipsum text here</p>
    </section>
    <aside></aside>
  </article>
  <article>
    <section>
      <h2>Building training</h2>
      <p>lorem ipsum text here</p>
    </section>
    <aside></aside>
  </article>
  <article>
    <section>
      <h2>Building training</h2>
      <p>lorem ipsum text here</p>
    </section>
    <aside></aside>
  </article>
</nav>
```

**Update:** Following some comments below, the `<nav>` is 100% of the window width and shifted left to remove the initial gap created by the skew. The `<aside>` is now `width: 110%` which removes the end gap.

**Update 2:** I was never happy with the `width:110%` to remove the end gap so I've now used `transform-origin: bottom center;` to make the skew leave the bottom edge alone (so the transformation is around the middle point on the bottom edge), thereby never actually creating an end gap! A few margins were adjusted for the text in the latest code too.

Comment: So basically, "How do I skew text without blur?", "Just don't do that".

Comment: @andyb Is there anyway to make these elements full screen, when I change the width because of the skew you can see white space to the left of the first element & right of the last element.

Comment: @Sam you can certainly add negative margin or relatively move the `<nav>`, or maybe `flex-grow` the elements across. Are there only 3 elements and do they need to take up 100% of the page width?

Comment: Yes, this is correct only 3 elements, I tried to offset an negative left on the first child, but couldn't get the last child to go right

Comment: I've updated my answer to remove the left gap created by skewing the `<aside>` and allowed the `<nav>` to fill the window width. There is still a gap at the end I'm still thinking about ways to remove!

Comment: Thank you, would it be worth using a clipping path, then the first child & last child could have square ends so you don't need to offset them. I'm not sure how this will work with the slanted border.

Comment: Example updated again, I've stretched the `<aside>` to fill the end gap

Comment: @andyb Thanks for all your help Andy I was just wondering why when the background image tag is used inline on ```aside``` element it skews the background but when the image is found from a class it doesnt?

Comment: @Sam I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Do you have a demo?

Comment: if the tag was the following; ```<aside style="background-image: url ;``` the skew will skew the background image so its tilted but when the image is set in the css rules it isn't

Comment: For me the image is skewed when declared in the CSS class or as inline style on the element. I can see this by toggling the `transform: skew(-15deg, 0deg)` rule on and off in the Chrome DevTools. Which browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Remove property "**-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;**" from your ::before ::after classes. so that it will work perfect.

It is worked For me. in Chrome, Firefox and Edge

```css
body{ margin: 0; }
.top { height: 100px; }
.main { 
background: linear-gradient(0deg, #FFFFFF 0%, #d1d1d1 100%);
position: relative;
color: #fff;  
z-index: 1;
color: #fff;
font-family: arial, sans-serif;
margin: 100px 0;
padding: 10% 10px;
text-align: center;}

.main:before{
  content:  '';
  background: #d1d1d1; 
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; 
  z-index: -1;
 /* -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;*/
  top: 0;
  transform: skewY(-5deg); 
  transform-origin: 1%;
}

.main:after{
  background: #d1d1d1;
  content:  '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0; 
  z-index: -1;
 /* -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; */
  top: 0;
  transform: skewY(5deg); 
  transform-origin: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="main">
  <h1>CONTENT</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether transforms causes blurriness are browser and renderer specific artifacts.

I find that Firefox tend to be able to render text after transformations without blurriness better than Chrome in general. Your example worked without modifications and without blurriness in Firefox (Linux, with Intel graphic).

In my machine, if you remove `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;` from `.driver`, Chrome will also render the text without getting blurry.

The better general solution is usually to avoid transforming texts. And instead add text after transforming everything else that isn't text.